# What percent of corner kicks turn into goals?

Tags: football, statistics

I have looked around for this statistic without luck.  I just wondered what percentage of corner kicks actually result in a goal? Not necessarily straight in, but from the same passage of play. I have seen answers (without any references) varying from 2.5% (feels too  low) to 32% (surely way too high).  Anyone know?

Comment: I doubt you will find an accurate percentage for this.. but 2.5% fells to high for me... if that percent is ok, in a weekend that you have 10 games.. and around 100 corner kick, you will have 2.5 goals.. no good since you usually don't have any for a lot of matches...

Comment: It will be really interesting to see the ratio of goals scored through corners to the total number of goals scored.

Comment: Related: [What percentage of football goals originate from corner kicks?](http://sports.stackexchange.com/q/1800)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The percent of goals from corners is changing from league to league, for one competition to another and for one year to another.
For example on 2010 World Cup 1 goal scored for every 70 corners taken,

but generally the ratio of corners to goals is almost **zero**.

Take a look at Ratio of Corners to Goal in the EPL
[image: 2010/11 Ratio of Corners to Goal in the EPL]

You can see that Fulham who has the best ratio has 0.07 goals for corner.

The most extensive articles I came across it was:
[soccerbythenumbers](http://www.soccerbythenumbers.com/2011/05/why-goal-value-of-corners-is-almost.html) and [scienceofsocceronline](http://www.scienceofsocceronline.com/2010/12/corner-kicks-by-numbers.html)

Comment: Reading through both articles, I think the answer that best fits my definition of scoring from a corner (I include goals scored from bad clearances after the corner too) is one in 40-45...that is about 2 - 2.5% much lower than I had imagined. Thanks for that.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this answer is not a good answer without at least a bit of quotation from the articles linked. Please do not post link only answers.

Comment: Picking up on the theme of variation between teams: FC Barcelona (as of 2014) generally don't even try a conventional corner kick (cross in the air hoping for a header) because [their players are so short](http://www.soccerbythenumbers.com/2011/07/tall-good-taller-better-height-and.html). The guys on TV always talk about how corners by other teams are more dangerous against Barça but I don't know where to find stats to verify that.

Answer (score 9):

You might be surprised to hear that the ratio of corners to goals is almost **nil**.

> On average, the data show that a corner is good for (drumroll ....) 0.022 goals. This means that the average EPL team scores 1 goal from a corner about every 10 games. And this helps to explain the lack of a correlation between the number of corners and goal scoring. The infrequency of the goals from corners combined with a lack of dispersion between teams in corners per game lead conspire to make corners mostly, well, useless when it comes to scoring goals.

[image: 2010/11 Ratio of Corners to Goal in the EPL]

> In this sample of matches, Fulham and Arsenal led the league in converting corner-created shots into goals at a rate of over .25, while at the low end, none of the shots created by Sunderland, Man City, Bolton, or Birmingham found the net.

- Source 1 : [Soccer by numbers](http://www.soccerbythenumbers.com/2011/05/why-goal-value-of-corners-is-almost.html)
- Source 2 : [Soccer by numbers](http://www.soccerbythenumbers.com/2011/02/goal-value-of-corners-zero.html)

**Copyright notice**:  The images and quotes posted above remain the sole property of the original owners and are posted here for educational purposes only.

Answer (score 7):

The chance that a goal will be scored off a corner kick appears to be **roughly 3%**.

[Michael Caley at the Washington Post](http://www.washingtonpost.com/news/fancy-stats/wp/2014/06/17/what-is-a-corner-kick-worth-in-soccer/) recently analyzed a set of nearly 13,000 corners taken in the English Premier League between 2011-2013, finding:

- Only 17 percent (2,157) "produced a legitimate shot attempt."
- Of those shot attempts, 370 were scores.

[image: Corner Kick Success Rate]
(data provided by Opta)

Caley links to [a study by Chris Anderson and David Sally at Soccer by the Numbers](http://www.soccerbythenumbers.com/2011/05/why-goal-value-of-corners-is-almost.html), which showed that EPL teams converted corners between 0-7% during the 2010/11 season, with the average team converting corners into goals at 2.2%. At that rate, the average team would score by corner kick about every 10 games.