# What percentage of football goals originate from corner kicks?

Tags: football, statistics

What are the odds that getting a corner kick result in a goal?

Note, I am not asking the percentage of corner kicks that result in a goal. I am after stats from pro-level soccer, for example, the EPL. Anyone know of any others?

Comment: You might want to narrow this down. What play level are you looking at? Professional defenders might be better at sweeping these out than your pee-wee leagues. This *might* not be answerable in its current state.

Comment: I will not downvote this question, but I really fell it need some localization to work. like the answers says, this change form league to league and from year to year.

Comment: The question in the title is different than the question in the first sentence. Perhaps consider editing one or the other.

Comment: Related: [What percent of corner kicks turn into goals?](http://sports.stackexchange.com/q/977)

Answer (score 2):

The question is very broad. However, taking statistics from the 2012-13 English Premiership (Games played till 29-Oct-2012), the total number of goals scored are 262, of which 36 are scored from corners. This gives a percentage figure of 13.74%

The breakup of each team are as follows.

```
+---------------------+---------------+--------------------+------------+
|         Team        |  Goals Scored | Goals from Corners | Percentage |
+---------------------+---------------+--------------------+------------+
|        Arsenal      |       14      |          1         |    7.14    |
|      Aston Villa    |        7      |          2         |   28.57    |
|        Chelsea      |       21      |          1         |    4.76    |
|        Everton      |       17      |          2         |   11.76    |
|        Fulham       |       19      |          3         |   15.79    |
|        Liverpool    |       12      |          1         |    8.33    |
|    Manchester City  |       18      |          3         |   16.67    |
|   Manchester United |       24      |          6         |   25.00    |
|    Newcastle United |       11      |          0         |    0.00    |
|      Norwich City   |        7      |          1         |   14.29    |
| Queens Park Rangers |        7      |          0         |    0.00    |
|       Reading       |       11      |          0         |    0.00    |
|      Southampton    |       14      |          3         |   21.43    |
|      Stoke City     |        8      |          2         |   25.00    |
|      Sunderland     |        6      |          0         |    0.00    |
|     Swansea City    |       14      |          1         |    7.14    |
|  Tottenham Hotspur  |       17      |          3         |   17.65    |
| West Bromwich Albion|       13      |          3         |   23.08    |
|   West Ham United   |       12      |          2         |   16.67    |
|    Wigan Athletic   |       10      |          2         |   20.00    |
+---------------------+---------------+--------------------+------------+
|        Total        |      262      |         36         |   13.74    |
+---------------------+---------------+--------------------+------------+
```

Comment: Wonderful, thanks. Was thinking it should be somewhere from 10-30%. Clearly a big part of offensive strategy for some teams. But interestingly, the top 5 teams in EPL standings now are all over the place w.r.t. success in corners, so definitely not the be-all, end-all. Arsenal(6) & Chelsea(2) are clearly benefiting from some solid defense so far this season, despite converting very few corners.

Comment: @Orangecrush - Can I please know your source from which the data has been taken?

Comment: 13.77% of 2010/11 Premiership goals were from corners. Source: http://bit.ly/SoiR1i

Answer (score 1):

This question is very general and can be change through time and league.

In the best research I found was from:
[Science and Football V: The Proceedings of the 5th World Congress on Science and Football](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=WTH-mDx9vUkC&pg=PA225&lpg=PA225&dq=notational+analysis+of+corner+kicks&source=bl&ots=JrtmVIw06h&sig=vLCngPwGmLcjP_CSHAvy3w-zoxg&hl=en&ei=7eiJSq7hDYHBlAeE6anmCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false).

> 20 English Premier League matched from 2001-02 season were randomly
>   sampled.
>   The analysed matches resulted in 59 goals scored with 6 (**10.2%**) as a
>   direct result of corner kicks.

Of course this can change between leagues and tournaments and through times.

Sources [1](http://nordeckeluchador.blogspot.co.il/2009/10/by-el-chupacabra-do-you-get-excited.html) [2](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=WTH-mDx9vUkC&pg=PA225&lpg=PA225&dq=notational+analysis+of+corner+kicks&source=bl&ots=JrtmVIw06h&sig=vLCngPwGmLcjP_CSHAvy3w-zoxg&hl=en&ei=7eiJSq7hDYHBlAeE6anmCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Why did the researchers sample here? You have all data right?

Comment: @Bernhard You can read the research

Comment: @DorCohen To Bernhard's point, some context relevant to the question being asked would make this answer that much more valuable.